# How to print the "instantiated" variable in Python OOP?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, instance-variables

I am studying the book "Learn Python the Hard Way" with Python3. The author presented the concept of OOP with this example:

```
class Song (object):

    def __init__(self,lyrics):
        self.lyrics = lyrics

    def sing_me_a_song(self):
        for line in self.lyrics:
            print (line)


happy_bday = Song(["Happy birthday to you", "I don't want to get sued","So I'll stop right there"])

bulls_on_parade = Song(["They rally around the family","With pockets full of shells"])

happy_bday.sing_me_a_song()

bulls_on_parade.sing_me_a_song()
```

OOP is kind of funny to me. The author suggest that we should "trash", "break" and "thrash" the code above a little bit.

I was trying to print the variable name in which the object was "instanced" (not sure if "instanced" is the correct word here, maybe the correct word is "instantiated"). In order to try that, I added the following methods on the class Songs():

```
class Song (object):

    def __init__(self,lyrics):
        self.lyrics = lyrics

    def sing_me_a_song(self):
        for line in self.lyrics:
            print (line)

    def name_of_var(self):
        print (Song)

    def name_of_var_2(self):
        print (object)

    def name_of_var_3(self):
        print (self)

    def name_of_var_3(self):
        print (self)
```

I used the examples of objects provided by the author:

```
happy_bday = Song(["Happy birthday to you", "I don't want to get sued","So I'll stop right there"])

bulls_on_parade = Song(["They rally around the family","With pockets full of shells"])

happy_bday.sing_me_a_song()

bulls_on_parade.sing_me_a_song()
```

Finally, I tried doing:

```
print(Song(["They rally around the family","With pockets full of shells"]))

print (happy_bday.name_of_var())

print (happy_bday.name_of_var_2())

print (happy_bday.name_of_var_3())

print (happy_bday.__init__(happy_bday))
```

I wasn't able to achieve my goal. Using the methods above I got:

```
<__main__.Song object at 0x7f4b784f3da0>
<class '__main__.Song'>
None
<class 'object'>
None
<__main__.Song object at 0x7f4b784f3d30>
None
None
pedr
```

My objective was to create some method in which I would do:

```
print (happy_bday.__some__method())
```

And the program would return:

```
happy_bday
```

Maybe that's not even possible in Python... If I am not wrong, you can do this type of thing in Lisp/Racket (but I am not 100% sure). Is this possible in Python? How can I do that?

Comment: There is no easy way to find out the "name" of the variable at runtime. That's not how variables _should_ work anyway. But if you really need it: You could have a look at `locals()`, `globals()`.

Comment: If that is what the book is saying you should do, I _highly_ recommend finding another book.

Comment: objects have no knowledge of the variables they have been assigned to. Anyway, that is *your* job of keeping track of that.

Comment: @ChristianDean, actually, the book just suggest that we should "play" with this code a little bit in order to get familiar with OOP. My approach with "playing"  is an unsual and strange way. The book did not suggest what I tried above.

Comment: So, just to be clear, variables *aren't instantiated*. *objects are instantiated*. Variables are *assigned to*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What's confusing you is that an object doesn't actually have a name! Let's say we create a Song using the `Song` constructor, and put it in a variable called `happy_bday`:

```
happy_bday = Song(["Happy birthday to you", "I don't want to get sued","So I'll stop right there"])
```

This creates a Song object, which lives on "the heap," an area of memory in your computer. It also creates a variable called `happy_bday`, which *refers to* the Song object you've just created. The Song object itself doesn't know this, though.

In fact, if you run

```
happy_bday2 = happy_bday
```

you will create another variable, `happy_bday2`, that refers to the *exact same Song object*. In fact, if you were to now run the line

```
happy_bday.lyrics[0] = "Happy Birthday To You"
```

to add some capitalization, the *lyrics of `happy_bday2` would also change*. That's because even though you have two separate variables, they are really just two ways of referring to the exact same object in memory.

Hopefully, it's now clear why you can't ask the Song object what variable refers to it; there could be multiple variables that refer to it, or no variables at all (after all, you could just write `Song(["some lyrics"]).var_name()`, in which case, what should be printed out?).

If you'd like to visualize this, there's a great tool called PythonTutor available here: http://pythontutor.com. You can type in your code, and see the variables and objects that are being created.

Answer (score 1):

Objects are not associated with names, rather they are associated with references.

If you truly want some means of identifying the object, allow a unique ID to be generated for each object and store it as a parameter. Heck, you can even do `self.uid = id(self)`.

Then, you can store a map of `{id : 'your_name_here'}`. Later, if you want, you can use the object's `uid` attribute to get its "name" (the one *you* gave).

Answer (score 1):

Others have commented on why what you want to do is unnecessary (and possibly undesirable). But it isn't actually true that it's impossible. After all, `globals()` is a dictionary of the objects and their references in global scope, and is designed for introspection of this sort. So you *could* define a method for your class that returns the names of all identifiers for an instance of that class. For example:

```
class Song():
    def __init__(self,lyrics):
        self.lyrics = lyrics
    def sing_me_a_song(self):
        for line in self.lyrics:
            print (line)

    def names_of_var(self):
       for k in globals().keys():
            if globals()[k] == self:
                print(k)

In [32]: happy_bday = Song(["Happy birthday to you", "I don't want to get sued","So I'll stop right there"])
In [33]: happy_bday2 = happy_bday
In [34]: happy_bday.names_of_var()
happy_bday
happy_bday2
```

Of course, this only works if you defined your `Song`s in global scope (not e.g. within some function).

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that. The name of your variable isn't part of the instance, and the instance doesn't know about it. As far as it is concerned, it has no name at all, or many, or maybe it is part of a list or so.

Like this:

```
>>> print(Song(["Line", "Line"]).some_method())
```

In this case, the instance is made, the method is called, and then the instance is thrown away again. It never had a name. What should it print?

Or this:

```
>>> name1 = name2 = Song(["Line", "Line"])
>>> name1.some_method()
```

Now the instance is referred to by two names, both name1 and name2.

```
>>> name1  = [Song(["Line"])]
```

Now it doesn't have a name itself, but there exists a list with a name that holds a reference to the song.

And so on. I hope this makes it a bit clearer. Instances exist apart from their names.